# What encryption and authentication algorithms does vsfpd use by default?

Tags: encryption, authentication, vsftpd

I have followed [this guide](http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/setup-ftp-server-on-ubuntu-14-04-vsftpd/) and was able to transfer files using SFTP, I want to know the encryption and authentication algorithms used by default in that file transfer.

Comment: Since you have used SFTP, even though the subsystem is from VSFTPD, the encryption would be from OpenSSH. Have a look at http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25662/openssh-default-preferred-ciphers-hash-etc-for-ssh2.